# If a subset of the real numbers has no cluster points it is countable

Tags: real-analysis

> Prove that if a subset of the real numbers has no cluster points it is countable.

I'd just like to see how this proof goes; preferably directly, if convenient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a brief outline of the contrapositive. We show that an uncountable set has a limit point; let $A$ be our set.

- At least one of the sets $A_n := [-n, n] \cap A$ must be uncountable (why?)
- Suppose that we've fixed $n$ from the above point. Bisect and get $[0, n] \cap A$ and $[-n, 0] \cap A$; one of these has to be uncountable (why?); call the appropriate interval $B_1$.
- Bisect $B_1$ and get an interval that's half as large, and contains uncountably many elements of $A$. Call it $B_2$.
- Bisect and get $B_3$. Continue.

Now $$\bigcap_{n = 1}^{\infty} B_n$$

contains a unique point (why?) that is an accumulation point of $A$ (why?).

---

Now a follow-up for you to think about: Why does this not work if $A$ is merely countable?

Comment: Please, answer the "whys".

Comment: @JohanLiebert The "whys" are left as an exercise to the reader because you'll learn a lot more by filling in the details yourself.

Answer (score 1):

If a set $A\subset \mathbb{R}$ has no cluster points, then $A\cap [-n,n]$ is finite (why?) for each $n\in \mathbb{N}$. Hence,
$$
A = \bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}} A\cap [-n,n]
$$
is a countable union of finite sets, and so countable.

Comment: They are isolated points?

Comment: @JohanLiebert : Can $A\cap [-n,n]$ be infinite? What does the Heine-Borel Theorem say?

Comment: Every closed and bounded subset of the reals is compact. So how does compactness imply countability?

Comment: Why is the intersection finite?

Comment: Compactness $\Rightarrow$ Sequential compactness. So what happens if $A\cap [-n,n]$ is infinite?

Comment: Then it would have an accumulation pt, yielding a contradiction?

Answer (score 0):

Let $A$ be any subset of $\mathbb{R}$ without cluster point.

**Approach 1**

For any $x \in \mathbb{R}$, $x$ is not a cluster point implies existence of an open neightborhood $B_x$ such that $A \cap B_x$ is finite. Shrink $B_x$ if necessary, one can make $B_x$ contains at most one point from $A$. More precisely, make $B_x \cap ( A \setminus \{x\} ) = \emptyset$. The collection of such $B_x$ forms an open cover of $\mathbb{R}$:

$$\mathbb{R} = \bigcup_{x\in\mathbb{R}} \{ x \}\subseteq \bigcup_{x\in\mathbb{R}} B_x$$

Since $\mathbb{R}$ is a [second-countable space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second-countable_space), it is a [Lindelöf's space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lindel%C3%B6f_space). i.e every over cover of it has a countable subcover.
This implies we can pick countably many $x_1, x_2, \ldots$ from $\mathbb{R}$ such that
$$A \subset \mathbb{R} = \bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty} B_{x_i}$$

Since each $B_{x_i}$ contains at most one point from $A$, $A$ itself is countable.

**Approach 2**

If one don't want to involve the concept of second-countablity or Lindelöf's space explicitly, one can prove the same thing by constructing an injection from $A$ into $\mathbb{Q} \times \mathbb{Q}$.

For each $x \in A$, pick a $B_x$ as before such that $B_x \cap A = \{ x \}$. One then choose $\ell_x, r_x \in \mathbb{Q}$ such that $x$ belongs to the open interval $( \ell_x, r_x ) \subseteq B_x \subseteq \mathbb{R}$

Since $A \cap ( \ell_x, r_x ) = \{ x \}$, the map $A \ni x \mapsto ( \ell_x, r_x ) \in \mathbb{Q} \times \mathbb{Q}$ is an injection.
Since $\mathbb{Q}$ is countable, $\mathbb{Q} \times \mathbb{Q}$ is countable and hence $A$ is at most countable infinite.